# Is there any difference between "nexus" and "locus"?

Tags: differences

As the question implies, I'm interested in only the semantical aspects of the two words I've listed. I've looked up these two words on some online dictionaries. After some searching, I've noticed that the third definition of *nexus* and the first/second definition of *locus* are nearly identical in meaning.

Cambridge Dictionary lists the definition of ***nexus*** as "an important connection between the parts of a system or a group of things"
Whereas ***locus*** is defined by the same online dictionary as "the place where something happens or the central area of interest in something being discussed:"
Here are some examples to expound my point:

Example 1: For us, the island had become the locus of the struggle.

Times Square is the nexus of the New York subway.

Example 2: The real nexus of the money culture was Wall Street.

The community is a locus of healing, not the hospital or the clinic.

In the two previous examples, my brain's understanding of these two words has led me to perceive them as sharing the definition of "a place or locality  as the cause or source of great activity".

Comment: I'm not sure if this is discussion is limited only to literary usage, but in math (geometry) the meaning of locus is expanded to "the set of all points that fulfill a given condition"; eg any circle can be described as "the set of all points equidistant from a given point". Thus any region could be regarded as a locus.

Comment: From your own research, you can see that the definition of nexus emphasises the **connection**, whereas **locus** is emphasises the aspect of place.

Comment: If you are looking for a difference, there seems little point in looking at similarities. The differences lie in the different definitions. These often represent use in different contexts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thank you for researching your question so carefully.  To the extent that there is a difference between these two words,you can most clearly see the difference by looking to their derivations.

Both are derived from (or simply **are**) Latin words.  The Latin *locus* means a *place*.  You might think of it as a dot on a map.  In Latin *nexus* is also a noun, meaning a 'bond'.  It, in turn, is derived from the verb *nectere* (past participle *nexus*) meaning to *bind* or *weave*.  The point about *nectere* is the it involves joining things together (threads, pathways, journeys... networks).  And yes, it seems that even the word *net* has the same derivation.

So Time Square in New York, Picadilly Circus in London, Charles de Gaulle Airport in Paris are both *loci* (the plural of second declension *locus* in Latin) and *nexūs* (the plural of **fourth** declension *nexus* pronounced *nexoose*, I'm sorry to say, because *necto* is a third conjugation verb!).  That is they are places and they are places where several journeys by car, foot or aeroplane meet.  And you can describe the networks themselves as nexūs (but don't worry, no one will stop you from calling them *nexuses*, just avoid *nexi* in case some pedant like me is standing nearby ready to judge).

So which of the two words you use is really a matter of which aspect you wish to emphasise, the point location or the intersection of different threads.

Comment: On the plural of *nexus*, my view is that English rarely adopts Latin fourth declension noun plurals so uses *-uses* rather than *-ūs* (another complication is related Latin adjective plurals often being different)

Comment: That 's right.  I had my tongue in my cheek as I wrote that.  In fact the only example of the plural provided by Cambridge is 'nexuses'.  Collins dictionary thinks the British English plural is 'nexūs', while the American English can be either 'nexūs' or 'nexuses'.  To me, both sit uncomfortably on the tongue, the latter because of the repeated sibilants, the latter because of its unfamiliarity.

Comment: English rarely adopts *any* Greek or Latin plurals, and usually gets them wrong when it does...

Comment: I remember in High School Latin wondering how the Romans told the difference between different forms of nouns in 4th and 5th declensions. Of course, I didn't realize then that mostly they didn't care, any more than we do. Also, you gotta be careful with the plural of _locus_ in English. Mathematicians use it often and _loci_ is pronounced /losai/  in math.

Comment: I don't know how long _nexus_ has been an English word, but I'd bet it's plenty long enough to consider it naturalised, and having earned its very own English plural!

Comment: I think you have a typo here, “*necto* is a third declension verb.” No “verb” is _any_ “declension.” Rather, *necto* is third *conjugation*.

Comment: So a nexus could always be described as a locus, but a locus could potentially just be a random point somewhere that is not really a nexus in any meaningful sense.

Answer (score 1):

From your own research, you can see that the definition of nexus emphasises the connection, whereas locus is emphasises the aspect of place.

OED: **Nexus:**

> **1.a. A bond, link, or junction; a means of connection between things or parts; (also) the state of being connected or linked.**
>
> 1996   N. Davies Europe 359   *The Crusades..served to strengthen the nexus between Western Christendom, feudalism, and militarism.*
>
> **2. A connected group or series; a network.**
>
> 1988   A. Storr School of Genius vi. 81   *The less a person feels himself to be embedded in a family and social nexus, the more he feels that he has to make his mark in individual fashion.*

OED: **Locus**

> **1.The place in which something is situated or occurs. In later use also: the effective or perceived location of something abstract.**
>
> 2006   Wired Sept. 178/2   *Record labels have always been the center of gravity in the industry—the locus of power, ideas, and money.*

> I've noticed that the third definition of nexus and the first/second definition of locus are nearly identical in meaning.

If you are looking for differences - and that is your question - do not be distracted by similarities, especially those that might only occur in rare contexts.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the difference between locus and nexus seems to be the order, in their meanings, of the point and line aspects. In 'locus', the point defines the lines; in 'nexus', the lines define the point.

Where a locus hosts a nexus, the latter is a focus of the former.

Of warp and weft, the loom is the locus, the fabric the nexus. Therefore, the latter is the focus of the former.